# How can I shorten a string to a specific number of words?

Tags: app-inventor

I linked google sheet file to a app and displayed all 'data' in list view, those are long sentences and I want to make it so only the first 5 words are displayed, not the whole thing

[image]
link to the excel list: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L2YPoJ0KH8OB80j-9wXHJ33SP0YB0aEI0xPt4nTzLpc/export?format=csv

Answer (score 0):

String myString="This is a string that is very long and tiring";

//get 10 characters max from the string
String formatedString=myString.substring(0,10);

System.out.println(formatedString);

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?hl=en)... There you can use SQLish commands...
For an example how to use the API in App Inventor see here https://puravidaapps.com/spreadsheet.php#select